# Convert XML url to JSON url in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, xml, angularjs

Is there a way to convert XML url to JSON url so that I can use it in my website ?

```
{"breakfast_menu": {
"food": [
  {
    "name": "Belgian Waffles",
    "price": "$5.95",
    "description": "Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup",
    "calories": "650"
  },
  {
    "name": "Strawberry Belgian Waffles",
    "price": "$7.95",
    "description": "Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream",
    "calories": "900"
  },
  {
    "name": "Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles",
    "price": "$8.95",
    "description": "Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream",
    "calories": "900"
  },
  {
    "name": "French Toast",
    "price": "$4.50",
    "description": "Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread",
    "calories": "600"
  },
  {
    "name": "Homestyle Breakfast",
    "price": "$6.95",
    "description": "Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns",
    "calories": "950"
  }
]}}
```

Suppose the URL is given as http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml then how can I convert that to JSON so that I can use it in AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [xml2json.js](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) to convert an XML to JSON

Be sure to read the [accompanying article on the xml.com](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/05/31/converting-between-xml-and-json.html), which goes into details of interesting problems with these conversions.

**Usage:**

```
  $scope.xml = '<breakfast_menu>'+
                '<food>'+
                   '<name>Belgian Waffles</name>'+
                   '<price>$5.95</price>'+
                '</food>'+
              '</breakfast_menu>';

  var dom = parseXml($scope.xml);
  $scope.json = xml2json(dom,"  ");
```

use `{{json}}` to display the json in your view!

```
{ "breakfast_menu":{"food":{ "name":"Belgian Waffles", "price":"$5.95" }} }
```

Here's a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gs1lcA22tk5zzEM7vGjn?p=preview)

Comment: In $scope.xml can I access url instead of data

Comment: ofcourse, you'd simply need to use `$http` service and get the `xml`

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment here is plunker [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q8jdsQLrBlNvECWEmDTz?p=preview)

Comment: @RamanaUday: Hi..I checked your plunker..and found following issues. - First, see the console for this error **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**. It is a **CORS** issue. Secondly..you are trying to do `$scope.xml = $http.get('...')`. `$http.get` service returns a **promise** and not the response data itself. So you cannot assign it to a variable straightaway.

Comment: Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdpSP5Pk83qDQpiIs2aj?p=preview). I have changed to url from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml to http://cdn.rawgit.com/motyar/bcf1d2b36e8777fd77d6/raw/bfa8bc0d2d7990fdb910927815a40b572c0c1078/out.xml to make it work. Regarding the CORS issue..see [this](http://enable-cors.org/). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Why is it not working for http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml same way it is not for my xml services too please can u help me regarding this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80774/discussion-between-ramana-uday-and-nln).

Answer (score -1):

@SFDC:Hi... This xml link('http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry') is possible to convert from xml to json format